# Angular 8, how to reference a component property inside a function of a javascript library

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I am using Semantic UI in angular and I have the following code:

```
componentProperty: boolean = false;

 ngOnInit() {    
    (<any>$('.ui.dropdown')).dropdown();
    
    (<any>$('.ui.input')).popup({
        on: 'focus', 
        onShow: (e) => {
            return this.componentProperty;
        }
    });
}
```

the function popup is defined by semantic UI. Semantic UI relies on Jquery.
Here componentProperty is undefined.

Comment: Please share the code where the componentProperty gets assigned a value. The code above just declares it so its value is undefined.

Comment: What do you see for temp as in: let temp = (<any>$('.ui.dropdown'))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This about scope. Try:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    const me = this;

    (<any>$('.ui.dropdown')).dropdown();
    
    (<any>$('.ui.input')).popup({
        on: 'focus', 
        onShow: (e) => {
            return me.componentProperty;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryed to define the onShow function in the components scope?

```
ngOnInit() {    
   const onShow = () => this.componentProperty;
   (<any>$('.ui.input')).popup({
      on: 'focus', 
      onShow
   });
}
```

And if that still won't work:

```
  const doOnShow = () => this.componentProperty;
  (<any>$('.ui.input')).popup({
      on: 'focus', 
      onShow: doOnShow.bind(this)
   });
```